# Where all do I set my character sets, when using JavaScript, PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, character-encoding

I'm trying to use UTF-8, but I'm not sure if I'm doing everything correctly.  I'm trying to write JSON to a database using PHP, retrieve it via AJAX, and display it in HTML.

So, firstly, I save my PHP & JS files in UTF-8 format.
I add the UTF-8 header to my PHP files.
The database table is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `achieve` (  
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,  
`json` mediumtext,  
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When saving to the database, I use the following PHP code:

```
$json=$_REQUEST["json"];
...
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    $query = sprintf(
        'UPDATE achieve SET json = "%s" WHERE id=%d ',
        mysql_real_escape_string($json), $ID
    );
else 
    $query = sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO achieve (id, json) VALUES (%d, "%s") ',
        $FBID, mysql_real_escape_string($json)
    ); 
mysql_query($query);
```

When I display the value in HTML, it still seems to be in the wrong encoding.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting everyone's time here... I figured out the answer to my question eventually!  I had been using escape() in JavaScript before saving my JSON to the database.  Apparently this only works with ASCII, and one should be using encodeURIComponent() instead.  Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the data is being stored correctly, using a database browser such as PHPMyAdmin or such? Try executing these two queries beforehand:

```
SET NAMES utf8
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Did you verify that the data is being stored correctly? You should identify where in the chain the character set is incorrect so you know where to fix it.

Comment: Any advice on an easy way to tell what format the data is stored in?